# Run same command again but as root

Tags: command-line, sudo

Sometimes when I run a command I don't notice that I needed to run it as super user to have enough permission.

Is there a way to run the same command again but as a super user?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

The simplest way is to run:

```
sudo !!
```

This will run the last command but as super user.

[Source](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/rerun-the-last-command-with-sudo-on-the-linux-shell/).

Comment: I found this quite useful and I hadn't come across it before (though it may be common knowledge). I couldn't find it on the site so I thought I would answer it myself.

Comment: As an aside, executing `!!` on its own runs your previous command as per saved in `history`. In addition, doing `!-1`, `!-2`, and so on executes your last command, second last command, and so on. Handy!

Comment: As an another aside, `!<command>` will execute last event from `~/.bash_history` that start with `<command>`

Comment: Your kung-fu is superior! I stand in awe! lol

Comment: ctrl-r is also very useful. it will search backwards in your history for commands matching what you type. This will allow you edit the command before running it again

Comment: This stupid `!` bash thing copied from `tcsh` has screwed me up more times than it's ever been useful.  Double quotes don't protect from the interpretation of `!`.  `$ foo "!bar"` -> `!bar: event not found`.

Comment: @Kaz you can disable history expansion with `set -H` - add that to your .bashrc to turn it off permanently.

Comment: Oops, I meant `set +H` to disable it.

Comment: @Kaz Using single quotes should leave the ! intact.

Comment: I've turned off this !-ity a long time ago (setopt nobanghist; that's zsh).

Answer (score 85):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[image]

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​*Answer:* you enter `sudo !!` straight afterwards to repeat the previous command with escalated privileges.

<sub>*edit:*  Image found via [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/f9gj6/), and it's a parody of the [original](http://xkcd.com/149/) xkcd comic by Randall Munroe.</sub>

Comment: please do not have a pro-or-against conversation here in comments.  If you wish to discuss the merits or otherwise, please use Meta.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You could try the up-arrow key to scroll through your old commands and rewrite/change them and add the `sudo` in front of them. (the home button above the arrow keys will set the position to the beginning.)

I dislike the `sudo !!` idea, because sometimes you add another command in between and don't remember anymore.

Comment: Fortunately, when you do `sudo !!`, the shell will expand `!!` so that you can see what command it's trying to run. So, it may end up being irritating to hit Ctrl-C and find the right command, but it at least won't take you unawares.

Comment: @Reid It won't expand until _after_ you hit enter, and if you're within that window where you don't have to enter your password again, it will run without confirmation.  +1 to using the history instead of blindly using `!!`

Comment: @Izkata: I suppose that's true. I use zsh, so I just type `sudo !!<TAB>` and it autocompletes `!!` for me. Bash can expand history with `M-^` (for me, alt+shift+6), but that's less fluent (you could rebind this, though).  There is also `shopt -s histverify`, which makes it so that when you use history expansion and hit enter, it instead gives you another prompt line with the expansion performed to let you see/edit it.

Comment: I was thinking more of the situation where I typed a command, the command returned that permission was denied, and I know I want to run this exact same command again but as sudo, the process of pressing up, home, typing sudo and feels much slower to me. It's the way I have been doing it forever and it just felt inefficient.

Comment: @Reid: `shopt -s histverify` won't help a single bit. Most people will get used to hitting `Enter` twice. At that point they're still too late to check what happened.

Comment: +1 to avoid the old fashioned !, when readline was not an option, I'm used to put set +H in my .bashrc

Comment: just use command expansion to unveil what the symbols represent. press `control-alt-e` before hitting enter to edit the bang bang !!

Answer (score 15):

This question could have been generalized into "*Run same command but with some modification*", since one of the brilliant design decisions in Unix, is that what's implemented once in the shell, can be leveraged by any command being invoked from the shell.

In other words, this trick doesn't apply **just**  to `sudo`:

- Repeat the previous command as superuser (`sudo !!`)
- Repeat the previous command and time it (`time !!`)
- Repeat the previous command with a different environment (`env A=b B=z !!`)
- Repeat the previous command (`!!`)

History expansion (also known as history substitution) is just a shell feature to make repeating previous commands easier (with less keystrokes). Check your shell man page for `history expansion`.  It describes many more tricks and short-cuts you can do with history for example:

You may refer to previous commands by number:

```
!55                 # repeat command number 55
!-1                 # repeat the previous command, alias for !!
!-2                 # repeat the command before the previous command
```

You may refer to individual words in previous commands:

```
some-command !$     # run some-command on the last arg of previous command
```

You can also search before repeating:

```
!?awk               # repeat the last command including the string 'awk'
```

You can search the history and replace something by something else:

```
!?awk?:s/str1/str2/  # repeat previous command matching 'awk' replacing str1 by str2
```

And much more, since you can combine command selection, arg-selection, search and replace independently.

The man page of your shell (in this case `man bash`) is your friend.

Comment: briliant! that one should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

I'll just add an alternative: **as short** as typing `sudo !!` and more flexible:

```
Up-arrow (once, or until you find the command you want to sudo/edit, if it's older)
ctrl+A   (place cursor at beginning of line)
"sudo "
Enter
```

It's exactly the same number of keystrokes (I count "ctrl+A" as one...), but adding "up arrow" you can do it on whichever command is in your history.

Comment: ctrl+A is from the emacs bindings, you can also use the vi bindings (`set -o vi`). Then you can Escape (go to command mode), and then 'I' (capital 'i', insert at beginning of line).

Comment: @GerhardBurger: I know, but, weirdly, I *love* vi (especially vim) for multi-line documents editing, but I do much prefer the emacs binding in the shell (having to switch from command to edit mode in the shell doesn't really makes sense, imo, and the shortcuts of emacs are quite enough for everyday use, even if less powerfull)

Comment: True, I added it just for completeness, for me it's the same, however I find searching with '/' very convenient ;)

Comment: @GerhardBurger: about vi mode's "/", regular (emacs binding) bash has also a very handy way to find previous commands by typing a few letters then 'ctrl+r' until you find it

Comment: Why not just use "home"? Then it actually is just one keystroke.

Comment: @leviathanbadger it is too far away to reach

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do this

- Simply enter the command again adding `sudo` before the command
- Press <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> to get the last command and put `sudo` in front of it.
- Enter `sudo !!`

The `!!` expands to the last entered command. You can do similar things with other things with the command line history see [here](http://chrisjean.com/2009/03/09/command-line-history-in-ubuntu-terminal/)

Answer (score 6):

I use [zsh](http://zsh.sf.net/) instead of bash and have this in my `~/.zshrc`, so pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> inserts `sudo` at the beginning of the command line:

```
insert_sudo () { zle beginning-of-line; zle -U "sudo " }
zle -N insert-sudo insert_sudo
bindkey "^[s" insert-sudo
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't track down a way to do the same thing in bash.

Comment: You can easily do the same in Bash using GNU Readline: add to your `~/.inputrc` `"\es":"\C-asudo "` and you will move to the start of a long line **and** sudo will be inserted at the start of the line upon pressing `alt-s`. Restart terminal or re-read `~/.inputrc` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in an alias, you have to use `alias redo='sudo $(history -p !!)'` for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The way I prefer it:

- Arrow key up
- Home
- "sudo "
- Enter

But it might be easier to just do "sudo !!", it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
su -c "!!"
```

If you do not have permission to be root with sudo or sudo program did not install on system.