# What does `!!` mean in `sudo !!`?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am a user of Ubuntu with not much experience and I have been using `sudo`.

What does `sudo !!` do and how?

Comment: Duplicate of, except from the other side: [Run same command again but as sudo](http://askubuntu.com/q/300832/11751)

Comment: @WarrenHill he doesn't want the "how" but the "what" and "how". He ask more about the `!!` part of the command.

Comment: @Nakilon shouldn't be. This question is asking what the `!!` do and how. The other wants a method to do this.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you meant related right?

Comment: @Braiam Actually, I did mean duplicate; the two highest-voted answers to that one specifically explain what `sudo !!` does, and there are two answers that actually specifically explain what `!!` does.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`!!` in bash is an alias for the previous command (see [Event Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators)). So it re-runs the previous command with `sudo` permissions.

Comment: Note: `!` commands are usually not available in bash scripts (only in interactive sessions). They can be disabled with `set +o histexpand`.

Answer (score 64):

`sudo bang bang` is a very useful command when working in Command Line Interface.

Some Linux distros have you login as a user instead of an administrator.

So, to do something admin-wise, you have to proceed the command with `sudo` (Super-User DO), which tells the system “you will do this, because I said so.” The !! / bang-bang (! = bang) is basically a shortcut you can use to repeat the previous command.

So, typical scenario is that you try a command, and it kicks back a message saying you have to be an admin to do that. So, you can either type `sudo` to run that command as super-user/admin, or you can type `sudo !!` where `!!` tells the system to use the previous command that was attempted.<sup>[UfH](http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.com/)</sup>

There are many other bang-commands.  For a list of them and explanations to what they are, check out [Linux Bang Commands](http://codytaylor.org/2009/09/linux-bang-commands.html), see also [Bash history and bang commands](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/bash_command_history_reuse.shtml)

Comment: It's also a very dangerous command if you're not 100% sure what your previous command was. It's almost always safer to just hit the up arrow, then the home key, then type `sudo` and look at the command line.

Comment: @Shadur Usually your previous command was about 1 second ago. The normal use case is the one described in the answer: you forget to `sudo` something and get an error, so you immediately want to `sudo` it

Comment: @Braiam: CLI is an abbreviation. Community rule violation! Attack! Re-edit!

Comment: `sudo` doesn't mean "super-user do", it goes as *do* a command *as if* I had done `su` (su meaning **switch** user [and not super user]); i.e., you can sudo commands as any user, not only root (`-u` switch); same goes with `su [user] [-c command]`

Comment: @ssice It can mean that.  See [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/), it explains it as su "do", and su stands for Super User.

Comment: @Mitch except `su` does not stand for such a thing. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/su , http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/su-invocation.html , http://www.linfo.org/su.html . It should mean *substitute user*.

Comment: root is just the *default user* that `su` substitutes you for, because (among other things) root (the user with UID=0) is the only user known to be existent in every Linux flavor.

Answer (score 38):

The `bang bang (!!)` command is a shortcut to **repeat and run the previous command** you entered in your terminal. This command is very useful when you forget that you need admin rights to make a certain action, and lets you repeat it with super-user rights just by typing,

```
sudo !!
```

`!!` grabs the last run command.

## For example:

```
apt-get update
```

The output will be,

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

After that,if we run `sudo !!` command,the output will be

```
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
Get:3 http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net saucy-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net saucy Release                             
99% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
```

Which means `!!` part grabs the previous run command `apt-get update` and the  preceeding `sudo` part makes the command to run with superuser rights.

And **how** the `sudo !!` runs the previous command with superuser privileges means,normally all the commands we entered on the terminal are stored in the `command history`.Run the `history` command on the terminal,it shows all the commands you entered.The `!!` part in the `sudo !!` grabs the last command stored in the command history and the whole `sudo !!` runs the last command with admin privileges.

Some other **bang commands** are explained in this [**blog post**](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2011/09/28/bang-bang-command-recall-in-linux.html#.UoouF3gsu4A).

Comment: I'm surprised to see it mentioned 'bang bang' again. I thought once was enough.

Comment: +1 for more examples of bang commands.

Comment: @Rmano At least in Bash, and I expect all Bourne-style shells with history support, `mkdir LongDirectoryName` and `cd !$` must be issued separately to work, unless `LongDirectoryName` happens to have been the last word of the preceding command. For shell history purposes, `mkdir LongDirectoryName; cd !$` is one command. History interaction with `!!`, `!^`, and `!$` use the last command the shell actually fully processed before seeing `!`. [Here's an example.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25419875/) If you run `history` you'll see that commands on a line joined by `;` are remembered as one command.

Comment: @EliahKagan you're right! Deleted wrong info...

Answer (score 13):

There are two parts to the answer: `!!` and `sudo`

`!!` is part of the functionality of the shell (in the case of Ubuntu this is probably bash, but other shells like zsh or csh support this, too) called "history expansion". It behaves in a similar way as other expansions in that the shell expands the 'placeholder' to a set of words. While `foo*` would be expanded to a list of all files starting with 'foo', `!!` gets expanded to the contents of the previous command line.

```
$ echo foobar
foobar
$ echo !!
echo foobar
$ !!
echo foobar
```

Like other expansions, this is done entirely by the shell, so if you type `!!` after some other command, this command is not aware that there was a `!!`, but will only see the previous command line. (Unlike other expansions, history expansion happens before a command is saved in the history, that is instead of `!!` the replaced command line will be saved to the history.)

---

The `sudo` command allows executing commands as another user, provided the permissions ar granted by the security policy (default is configured in `/etc/sudoers`).

By default the root password remains unset in Ubuntu. In order to perform system administration tasks the user created during installation is granted sudo rights. This user can now execute any command on the shell as root, just by prepending `sudo`. Some GUI programs use the sudo mechanism, too, for example package management.

The reason why `sudo` can execute other commands as root (or another user) is that the sudo binary (`/usr/bin/sudo`) has the setuid bit set in its permission and belongs to root. Any (binary) executable with set setuid bit is run with the permissions of its owner. This means that sudo runs effectively with root permissions no matter which user actually called it. Only he internal security policies of sudo manage which user is allowed what and prevent arbitrary users to do arbitrary things.

---

So, in the case of `sudo !!` this means

```
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: only root can do that
$ sudo !!
```

is basically identical to

```
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: only root can do that
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

just less typing. In both cases sudo just sees `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and runs it with root permissions.

Answer (score 5):

`!!` is the syntactically simplest and probably most common expression for [history expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction).

As you may have noticed, after substituting the last command executed for `!!`, bash does two things (in its default configuration):

1. The full command with the substituted text is shown to you.

   For example, if your command was `lshw -c video` and you run `sudo !!` next, then the command after history expansion is `sudo lshw -c video`.
2. That command is run.

Normally these two steps occur without interruption and with no opportunity for user interaction, because `shopt histverify` is unset by default (`shopt -u histverify`).

However, if you enable `shopt histverify` (`shopt -s histverify`) then history expansion works differently:

1. You get a new primary prompt, with the expanded text automatically entered on it. It is as if you had typed that text yourself, with the cursor at the end, but have not yet run the command.
2. You, the user, must then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command. Or you may edit the command, cancel it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), etc. Note that this is not a special prompt, but a regular primary prompt. It really is as though you typed the text yourself.

(Note that the `histverify` [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) takes effect only if [the readline library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is being used--but when you use bash interactively on an Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux system, this is essentially always the case.)

*Whether or not the `histverify` shell option is enabled*, history expansion is dissimilar to many other shell expansions. Other shell expansions do not show you the expanded command before it is run. Unlike other expansions, which are intended to be used both interactively and noninteractively (for example, in a shell script), history expansion is almost always used interactively.

Answer (score 3):

! is used in Linux for history related shortcuts. So, !! will simply run the previous command you executed.

It's very helpful in cases when you either forget to put sudo before a command that requires it or you get Permission Denied or something like that just do

```
sudo !!
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

!! will repeat and run the previous command , and with sudo it will give the command the root privilege. 
 **( It is not in man page ?!!  I can not see it there.)**

Comment: For anyone looking for the man page: `man --pager='less -p "Event Designators"' bash`